# Combine the queries (SELECT + UPDATE)

Tags: mysql

I have the queries that I want to combine to one. But I can't seem to get it working. What to do?

This is number one:

```
SELECT MIN(publish_date) publish_date, magazine_id
FROM published
GROUP BY magazine_id
```

This is number two:

```
UPDATE magazine SET first_published_on = :publish_date WHERE id = :magazine_id
```

In this case I want to use the data from the SELECT query into the UPDATE query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: select and update are two commands that should execute separately. you need to use stored procedure to do multiple tasks. do within transaction so this will be unique.

Comment: @e03050 Plainly, that's not quite correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below using UPDATE JOIN

```
UPDATE magazine
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(publish_date) publish_date, magazine_id
    FROM   published
    GROUP BY magazine_id
) a ON a.magazine_id=magazine.id
SET first_published_on = a.publish_date
```